# How to disable Sonatype Scan Spring-Web

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm getting security vulnerabilities for spring web jars in Sonartype scanning, leading Bamboo builds failure.

My question is how to disable the Sonar from scanning these jars?  Something like, configure in Gradle, Maven or Bamboo?

We already use 2.2.* version SpringBoot, so upgrade is not considered.

Thanks in advance.